# When I make a post request to add a new user, it doesn't save anything and I can't think of any reason why. Any ideas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making an app with express and mongoose, https://github.com/findjashua/express_app

- `app.coffee`

  ```
  app.post '/user', user.add
  ```
- `models/user.coffee`

  ```
  createUser = (req) ->
      user = new User
          name : req.body.name
          email : req.body.email
          phone : req.body.phone
      return user

  # ...

  exports.add = (req, res) ->
      user = createUser req
      res.send dbService.save(user)
  ```
- `services/db.coffee`

  ```
  exports.save = (document)->
      document.save (err)->
          if err
              console.log err
          return document
  ```

When I make a post request to add a new user, it doesn't save anything and I can't think of any reason why. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly isn't working. curl -X POST localhost:3000/user -d "name=MyName&email=test@test.com&phone=123456" works for me. The new user is stored in the mongo database under dbs 'temp', collection 'users'. How do you test? Do you have any error messages/logs?

Comment: Please include the relevant code within the question so the it doesn't lose its value after the contents of the link have changed. I've edited to include my take on "*relevant*." Edit as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.save()` is asynchronous, so `return` isn't really an option within `dbService.save()`.

- The `res.send()` will have already finished before `return document` is evaluated.
- It also returns `document` to the code that called the callback, which is within `document.save`, not to your code within `user.coffee`.

You'll need to adjust `dbService.save()` to accept a callback so you can `res.send()` the finished `document`:

```
exports.save = (document, callback) ->
    document.save (err, document) ->
        if (err)
            callback(err)
        else
            callback(null, document)
```

```
exports.add = (req, res) ->
    user = createUser req
    dbService.save user, (err, user) ->
        res.send err ? user
```

Note: that 1st snippet can be simplified, depending on whether or not `.save()` needs to do anything else:

```
exports.save = (document, callback) ->
    document.save callback
```

Comment: Oh, offcourse, I clearly wasn't thinking. Thanks so much.